# Create Asset with MindSphere

Tags: cloud, mindsphere

I want to create an asset with aspects and write/read data to/from it.

The [MindSphere API Document](https://developer.mindsphere.io/resources/mindsphere-sdk-java/sdkreadme/index.html) says that assets can be created using the API. Do you have a running code example for creating an asset via the API?
Is it also possible to create it with the Web-GUI? If so, which account is necessary for that (type)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you have a running code example for creating an asset via the API?

At [developer.mindsphere.io](https://developer.mindsphere.io/apis/index.html) you will find the API documentation with examples. Specifically for an asset creation you'll need the [Asset Management Service API](https://developer.mindsphere.io/apis/advanced-assetmanagement/api-assetmanagement-overview.html). I recommend to play with APIs with an API testing tool of your choice, like for example [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/).

> Is it also possible to create it with the Web-GUI?

Sure, every MindSphere tenant has a web tool/app called "[Asset Manager](https://documentation.mindsphere.io/resources/html/asset-manager/en-US/index.html)", which allows you to define Assets, Asset Types and Aspects usung the web GUI only.